# Pronunciation of the word “reduct” as a noun

Tags: pronunciation

How should I pronounce the word *reduct* as a noun?

Comment: Where is reduct used as a noun?

Comment: There is no noun form of *reduct* in any English usage I'm aware of. The *verb* form barely exists and is pretty much archaic at this point. Possibly you want the word *reduction*?

Comment: Or maybe "reductant," which refers to a chemical agent?

Comment: In maths and chemistry, according to the OED.

Comment: @chaos 'reduct' as a noun exists and is alive.

Comment: What did the dictionary say to do? Surely this is a textbook case of a general reference question, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might help, from OED

reduct, n.

Pronunciation:  Brit.    /rᵻˈdʌkt/ , U.S. /rəˈdək(t)/ , /riˈdək(t)/

The meaning of reduct as a noun is:

1. Math. and Logic.

a. A number, logical form, etc., obtained by reducing another

b. A mathematical or logical structure derived from a given structure by disregarding some of the operations and relations of the latter.

1. Chem. A substance which restores a metal to an unchanged or metallic state.